# Creating csv file from list using python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am new in python. I have a problem in creating a csv file from a list using python. I have a list like this:

```
mylist = ['Steve, Male, 28 years, 170 cm, 60 kg',
          'Anna, Female, 26 years, 163 cm, 55 kg',
          'Joe, Male, 27 years, 174 cm, 63 kg']
```

I want to create a csv file from the list above by adding header and removing units in the numeric data value. What I want will be like this:

```
+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
| name      | sex    | age |height|weight|
+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
| Steve     | Male   | 28  | 170  | 60   |
+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
| Anna      | Female | 26  | 163  | 55   |
+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
| Joe       | Male   | 27  | 174  | 63   |
+-----------+--------+-----+------+------+
```

This is my code so far:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    header = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight']
    writers = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writers.writerow(header)
    for row in mylist:
        writers.writerow([row])
```

I got stuck with the code.

Comment: you can read https://learnbatta.com/blog/reading-and-writing-csv-files-using-python-12/

Answer (score 1):

The complete solution would be:

```
with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    header = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight']
    writers = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writers.writerow(header)
    for row in mylist:
        writers.writerow([x.split()[0] for x in row.split(', ')])
```

BTW I don't see the need for `newline=''`

Here's the explanation of the magic happening in the last line of code:
we're splitting the row by delimiter containing a comma and a space. Then we are taking the first word of every item (that's the `.split()[0]` part).

Answer (score 0):

Your myList is a single list. Either make it a list of list, with each entry in mylist being each row of this sort, and then use your code:

```
mylist = [['Steve, Male, 28 years, 170 cm, 60 kg'],
          ['Anna, Female, 26 years, 163 cm, 55 kg'],
          ['Joe, Male, 27 years, 174 cm, 63 kg']]
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use the below code
- numpy is used in the below code

  ```
  import numpy as np

  mylist = ['Steve, Male, 28 years, 170 cm, 60 kg',
        'Anna, Female, 26 years, 163 cm, 55 kg',
        'Joe, Male, 27 years, 174 cm, 63 kg']

  table = np.array(["name", "sex", "age" , "height", "weight"])    


  for i in range(len(mylist)):
      row = np.array(mylist[i].split(","))
      table = np.vstack((table, row.reshape((1, row.shape[0]))))

  np.savetxt("result.csv", table, fmt='%s', delimiter=",")
  ```

## Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using **pandas** (the go-to library for tables today):

```
import pandas as pd

header = ['name', 'sex', 'age', 'height', 'weight']

mylist = ['Steve, Male, 28 years, 170 cm, 60 kg',
          'Anna, Female, 26 years, 163 cm, 55 kg',
          'Joe, Male, 27 years, 174 cm, 63 kg']

df = pd.DataFrame((i.split(', ') for i in mylist), columns=header)
df.to_csv('data.csv',index=False)
```

Creates:

```
name,sex,age,height,weight
Steve,Male,28 years,170 cm,60 kg
Anna,Female,26 years,163 cm,55 kg
Joe,Male,27 years,174 cm,63 kg
```